# Getting 'activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName()' to change dynamically

Tags: javascript

Please see the picture below

[image]

I have this GoogleSheets spreadsheet with a BUNCH of tabs (sheets) in it. The following code needs to run for EVERY sheet:

```
function SearchCols() 
{
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"),                     
    searchVal = sheet.getRange("L7").getValue(),                                              
    searchCol = sheet.getRange('L11:L30').getValues();                                        
    searchCol1 = sheet.getRange ('R11:R30').getValues();                                      
    searchCol2 = sheet.getRange('Q11:Q30').getValues();                                       
    searchCol3 = sheet.getRange('S11:S30').getValues(); 
    searchCol4 = sheet.getRange('T11:T30').getValues();

for (var i = 0, len = searchCol2.length; i < len; i++)                                          
for (var j = 0, len2 = searchCol1.length; j < len2; j++)                                       
    {
      if (searchCol2[j][0] == searchVal && searchCol1[j][0] == searchCol[i]
[0])               
      {
        sheet.getRange('N11:N10').setValue;                                                   
        sheet.getRange(i + 11, 14).setValue(searchCol3[j][0])                                 
        sheet.getRange(i + 11, 15).setValue(searchCol4[j][0])                                 
      } 
    }
}
```

It just some code to loop through a column to see if any values match with another column, and if so, paste some data into adjacent cells.

The code works, BUT...

See the 3rd line of code? Where it says: ".getSheetByName("Sheet1")"???

How do I change that "Sheet1" part so it DYNAMICALLY knows what sheet I'm on in order to run the code FOR THAT SPECIFIC SHEET?

I have a 'Run' button in EVERY sheet of my file, but I ONLY want this code to run for the sheet that I press the button in. (look at the attached screenshot!)

The way it is right now, if I'm in Sheet50 and I press the button to run this code, it will produce the results in Sheet1, but I need it to produce results in Sheet50! The same applies for every sheet of my file. When I press the 'Run' button, I need the code to ONLY run for that specific sheet.

Please help, dear friends!

Comment: I think I may have found it. Is it this??? Because it seems to work!:

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

Answer (score 0):

To loop through all of your sheets:

Get all of the sheets in the spreadsheet using `.getSheets()` then use a `for` loop to iterate through all of the sheets in the spreadsheet.

This is your code modified to work as you asked:

```
    function SearchCols() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();

    for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
        var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheets[i].getName());

        var searchVal = sheet.getRange("L7").getValue();
        var searchCol = sheet.getRange('L11:L30').getValues();
        var searchCol1 = sheet.getRange('R11:R30').getValues();
        var searchCol2 = sheet.getRange('Q11:Q30').getValues();
        var searchCol3 = sheet.getRange('S11:S30').getValues();
        var searchCol4 = sheet.getRange('T11:T30').getValues();

        for (var x = 0, len = searchCol2.length; x < len; x++) {
            for (var j = 0, len2 = searchCol1.length; j < len2; j++) {

                if (searchCol2[j][0] == searchVal && searchCol1[j][0] == searchCol[x][0]) {
                    sheet.getRange('N11:N10').setValue;
                    sheet.getRange(x + 11, 14).setValue(searchCol3[j][0])
                    sheet.getRange(x + 11, 15).setValue(searchCol4[j][0])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```